# Problema al hacer push en git al cambiar el nombre de la rama local

Tags: git, github

tengo un problema y por que  cambie el nombre de la rama local main a 'local'. Ejecute esto:

```
git config --global init.defaultBranch local
```

Todo bien, me cambio el nombre pero ahora cuando intento hacer un 'push' me responde:

```
error: src refspec local no concuerda con ninguno
error: falló el empuje de algunas referencias a 'https://github.com/estrella/git.git'
```

Supongo que tendre que renombrar la rama en gitHub pero no veo como hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Has hecho algún commit después del cambio?. ¿Qué de devuelve `git show-ref`?.

Comment: Hola Sal gracias por responder. Lo primero es que el repositorio que tengo no es importante solo estoy practicando leyendo el libro de GIT. A ver no tenia ningún commit hecho, hice uno y ya me dejo hacer push. Ahora la duda que tengo es si quiero cambiarle el nombre a la rama 'origin' por ejemplo llamarla servidor·

Comment: Creo que el error es porque no has renombrado la rama localmente. Tienes que hacer `git branch -m local` ya estando sobre la rama (o `git branch -m master local` si no estás en ella). Lo que hace ese ajuste que hiciste en la configuración es indicarle a git que cuando cree un repositorio _nuevo_, localmente, la rama por defecto se llame `local`

Comment: `origin` normalmente no es una rama sino un `remoto`.... Y a un remoto se le puede cambiar el nombre sin problemas: `git help remote`.

Comment: Buenas tardes @eftshift0. Me funciono, solo una cosa. La directiva que tengo en .gitconfig [ defaultBranch = local ] sirve para que 'local' sea la rama predeterminada, pero la tienes que crear. Osea que cuando clonas un repositorio o lo inicializas la rama local se crea como ' main ' no como local. Luego tienes o que crear la ' local ' o renombrar la 'main'. Pero vamos utilizando los comandos que has puesto lo he conseguido. Se ha quedado casí:  En la rama local
Tu rama está basada en 'server/main', pero upstream ha desaparecido.
  (usa "git branch --unset-upstream" para arreglar)

Comment: Buenas tardes @eftshift0. Me funciono, solo una cosa. La directiva que tengo en .gitconfig [ defaultBranch = local ] sirve para que 'local' sea la rama predeterminada. Cuando clonas un repositorio o lo inicializas la rama local se crea como ' main ' . Luego tienes o que crear la ' local ' o renombrar la 'main'. Use los comandos que has puesto lo he conseguido.                                                                                                               En la rama local
Tu rama está basada en 'server/main' pero upstream ha desaparecido.         Luego elimine upstream. Gracias